# Is there a word for an "infinite algorithm"?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, computational-mathematics

According to Knuth's [notes](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2104/Fall12/notes/T16_Algorithms.pdf) (see Slide 3), an *algorithm*, by definition, satisfies the following five properties:

1. *Finiteness*: Terminates after a finite number of steps.
2. *Definiteness*: Each step is precisely defined.
3. *Input*: Has zero or more inputs.
4. *Output*: Has one or more outputs, each of which has a specified relation to the inputs.
5. *Effectiveness*: All operations are sufficiently basic that they may be performed exactly and in finite length.

Is there a term for something that satisfies steps 2-5 and also 1 with the word *finite* replaced by *countable*?

Comment: If it is an infinite number of steps, how do you even define "terminates"?

Comment: @ClementC. By "terminates", I mean that an output is produced after a countable number of steps. This doesn't make sense in real-life obviously, but we could make it precise in an abstract or mathematical sense.

Comment: The whole purpose with *algorithm* is to calculate the answer. If it has infinite number of steps it is practically useless (=impossible).

Comment: @P.Turner One way to make sense of this question could be to look at *randomized* algorithms, whose *expected* running time is $t(n)$ for some function $t$. (see the class [ZPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPP_(complexity)), for instance.) Note that the algorithm will still terminate in a finite number of steps with probability $1$; but that number could be arbitrarily large (although with very small probability).

Comment: @A.G. Yes, I agree. But that does not negate the fact that I need a term for something with the specified property.

Comment: @P.Turner In what you are looking for, the output would have to be infinite as well, right? Otherwise, if the output is obtained after a finite number of steps (as must be the case for a finite output), then for all matter one can stop the "algorithm": it does not and will not produce anything anymore.

Comment: @ClementC. That is an interesting point, but it won't give me what I'm looking for. You see, I have a "infinite procedure" that will solve a given problem. Obviously this is useless in itself, but my hope is that this infinite procedure can be modified in some way to become a bona-fide algorithm. I'm trying to make it clear to my readers that what we have developed is not, strictly speaking, an *algorithm*, but hopefully with more results, it could become one.

Comment: Maybe *iterations* or a *sequence*?

Comment: @ClementC. The output, in a certain case, may *not* be obtained after a finite number of steps.

Comment: "computer program" (in the original acceptation of the term) would probably work, wouldn't it? At least, this is the term used to describe the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @ClementC. Computer programs should be aliens here. Brrr...

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I think the term "program" would work. Since our paper is in mathematics, I would prefer to not insist on the existence of a computer or an implementation of said program :).

Comment: A Turing machine? If you really want to formalize it in a clear and non-ambiguous way. But that does emphasize one particular "implementation."

Comment: @A.G. Computer programs are not conditioned on the existence of computers -- I did specify "original meaning," as in e.g. Turing's work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out

- [*Infinite Time Turing Machines*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808093) by Joel David Hamkins and Andy Lewis,
- [*A Survey of Infinite Time Turing Machines*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74593-8_5) by Joel David Hamkins,
- [*Infinite Time Turing Machines: Supertask Computation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212047) ( - "an expository account [...] for a philosophical audience" - ) by Joel David Hamkins,
- Wikipedia: [Supertask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask), [Hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation).